# how can I get response of cross site request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made a cross site request and the server is not in my control,.

So how can I get the response value?

I can see the response json value in the console of Firefox as shown below :

[image]

Comment: Are those quote(") marks normal quote marks or the fancy unicode ones?

Comment: I think these are normal quote marks

Comment: add your request code

Comment: `$.get(
   url,
   function(data){
    alert("test");
   },
   "jsonp"
   );`